# Android: Installed APK Certificate SHA-256 Fingerprint Mismatch with App's Certificate SHA-256 Fingerprint

Tags: android, apk, sha256, android-fingerprint-api

In my Android project, I encountered a frustrating issue where the certificate fingerprint SHA-256 of the installed APK does not contain the SHA-256 fingerprint of the app's certificate for some users. This mismatch is causing problems with my app's functionality, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I've verified that the certificate and keystore used to sign the app are the same for all users. I've also ensured that I'm using the correct signing configuration.

Here's the code which I used to compare the SHA-256

```kotlin
// Get list of Installed APK's Signature's SHA-256
private fun getSignatures(): List<String>? {
    val packageInfo = getPackageInfo() ?: return null
    return try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            if (packageInfo.signingInfo == null) {
                return null
            }
            
            if (packageInfo.signingInfo.hasMultipleSigners()) {
                signatureDigest(packageInfo.signingInfo.apkContentsSigners)
            } else {
                signatureDigest(packageInfo.signingInfo.signingCertificateHistory)
            }
        } else {
            val signatures = packageInfo.signatures
            if (signatures.isNullOrEmpty() || signatures[0] == null) {
                null
            } else {
                signatureDigest(signatures)
            }
        }
    } catch (exception: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        Utility.sendException(exception)
        null
    }
}

private fun getPackageInfo(): PackageInfo? =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(
            PACKAGE_NAME,
            PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES.toLong())
        )
    } else {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(
            PACKAGE_NAME,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES
            } else {
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
            }
        )
    }

// Method to create a list of SHA256 APK signatures
private fun signatureDigest(sigList: Array<Signature>?): List<String>? {
    if (sigList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return null
    }
    
    return mutableListOf<String>().also {
        sigList.forEach { signature ->
            it.add(getSignatureSha256(signature.toByteArray()))
        }
    }
}


private fun getSignatureSha256(certificate: ByteArray): String {
    val md: MessageDigest
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256")
    } catch (exception: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        Utility.sendException(exception)
        return ""
    }
    
    md.update(certificate)
    return md.digest().joinToString(":") { String.format("%02x", it) }
}

// Test method to compare APK's fingerprint with the Public key of the signing credentials of the app
fun test(): Boolean {
    return getSignatures()?.contains(APP_SHA256)
}
```

This is working fine for all my test devices, but when I put this APK for some real users, it returned false for many of them, while also being successful for most of them. I don't think so these many users would be using a modified version of the app.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before, and if so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you upload signed APK files to Google or to the distribution server? Have you considered that people resign your app and for this reason the signature is different? BTW: A certificate does not contain the certificate fingerprint, the SHA-256 fingerprint is the SHA-256 digest of the whole certificate data (which included all values and the public key). So if the fingerprint is different then the certificate and thus the signature is different.

Comment: Yes, I upload my signed APK to Google Play Console. Yes, people have been making a clone, modifying and resigning the APK, which is why I added the signature check. I am confused as to why for such a large number of my userbase, the signature is mismatching

Comment: How many different signatures do you see and many users of each sign? That would explain if there is one person modifying and distributing your app or if there are multiple versions then there may be modification tool like lucky patcher which allows to enhance or tweak or cheat something in your app.

Comment: Actually, I'll need to debug this in-depth as this issue I am facing is in Production. For whatever test build I had on various test devices, I just got one signature even for an app version where I imitated the app clone using an app cloner similar to Lucky patcher. Will add logs for the signatures I got for Mismatch cases.